# php $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] loses string query

Tags: php

I'm having difficulties to redirect users to the page that they pasted into browsers url.
I have a checklogin file that checks if users are logged in or not. in not they are redirected to login.php page.

Scenario:
When a user is not logged in and types an url like this 
http://intra.friends.net/forum/index.php?id=1&show=29&count=1
User logs in and should be redirected to the typed url.

Now it doesn't work as it should. 
checklogin checks if user not logged in and the redirects to logout.php and logout.php redirects to login.php

checklogin.php

```
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
if ($logged_in == 0 && (!isset($_COOKIE['autologin'])))
{
    $goback ="http://intra.tobiasfransman.net/hallinta/logout.php?temp=$url";
    header ("Location: $goback");
}
```

logout.php

```
$url = $_GET['temp'];
if ($logged_in == 0)
{
    $goback ="http://intra.tobiasfransman.net/login.php?select=$url";
    //$goback ="http://intra.tobiasfransman.net/login.php";
}
```

login.php

```
$url = $_GET['select'];
```

Problem here is that the $url dosent contain the whole link it misses the string query:
it looks like this:

```
/forum/index.php?id=1
```

when it should look like this:

```
/forum/index.php?id=1&show=29&count=1
```

It looses the string query.. anyway I could get this working?

Comment: [What every web developer must know about URL encoding](http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding) - Take a good look at the redirect URL again and think twice about what a `&` means in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you do not encode your query strings.

```
$url = urlencode($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
if ($logged_in == 0 && (!isset($_COOKIE['autologin'])))
{
    $goback ="http://intra.tobiasfransman.net/hallinta/logout.php?temp=$url";
    header ("Location: $goback");
}
```

That should give you the entire url in $_GET['temp'] in your logout.php witch in turn should make $_GET['select'] in your login.php return the entire url.

Comment: Hi, still it only prints out the /forum/index.php?id=1 on the login.php page, it breaks after the id=1

Comment: The browser url now shows it correctly like this: login.php?select=/foorumi/index.php?id=1&go=1&page=2&show=129 but what I don't get is when picked up using $_GET['select'] on login.php page and echoed out it only shows /foorumi/index.php?id=1

Answer (score 1):

As you are putting the request uri as a GET var in another url, you need to escape it first:

```
$url = urlencode($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```